# How to fetch those user list which are not assigned during particular date and time from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried many logics but still not getting accurate result.
I have 2 fields shift_from and shift_to with **datetime**. Same fields exists in database also.
Now i have to check that which uses are not assigned any shift during particular from and to date with time.

**Expected Result:**
 Query should return list of user which are not occupied during the entered date and time.

**Tables used:**

1. users -containing users date.
2. role_users - to determine the user's role.
3. roles - to determine the role list.
4. shift- to determine the shift details like timing,date,location etc.
5. company - to identify company related users only.

> Note: I am getting shift_from datetime from a form and shift_to datetime from from.

**MY Efforts:**
My query is as follows:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name FROM users as u
left join role_user as ru on u.id=ru.user_id 
left join roles as r on ru.role_id=r.id
left join shift_assignment as saa on saa.user_id=u.id
left join shifts as s on s.id=saa.shift_id 
left join companies as c on u.company_id= c.id 
WHERE r.name='security_officer_agents' and 
c.id=$company_id and ((DATE('$shift_from_date') NOT BETWEEN DATE('s.shift_from') and DATE('s.shift_to') and TIME('$shift_from_time') NOT BETWEEN TIME('s.shift_from') and TIME('s.shift_to')) or (DATE('$shift_to_date') NOT BETWEEN DATE('s.shift_from') and DATE('s.shift_to') and TIME('$shift_to_time') NOT BETWEEN TIME('s.shift_from') and TIME('s.shift_to'))
```

please help me on this.There is also a way to avoid not between because it is not considering that day .it is only taking between those dates.

**Shift Table structure**

```
'id', 
`location_id` ,   
`duty_point_id`,    
`contact`,    
`phone`,   
`shift_from`,    
`shift_to` ,    
`created_by` ,    
`created_at`,     
`updated_at`,   
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),    
KEY    `shifts_location_id_foreign` (`location_id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply condition like this,

```
fromtimedbfieldname < '$endtimephpvarible' 
AND 
totimedbfieldname > '$starttimephpvarible'
```

this condition solve your problem.

```
s.shift_from < $shift_to_date
AND
s.shift_to > shift_from_date
```

like above you have to replace. if user has been assigned between these dates it will return true.

```
$shift_to_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($shift_to_date))
```

Comment: I have to replace what code with this/.? please explain some logic regarding this and working also

Comment: What about time slots

Comment: can you just paste your db structure of 'shift' table?

Comment: yeah sure...check now

Comment: type of shift_from is DATETIME or DATE??

Comment: DATETIME DATA TYPE and please consider check suppose a shift having date from 5-10-2015 to 7-10-2015 and time 2 to 3..if another user will add a shift from 6-10-2015 to 8-10-2015 then your condition will work ?

Comment: then you can use above code. just format the date like {$shift_to_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($shift_to_date))} . Don't consider about timeslot.

Comment: i am already doing this like so
$shift_from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Request::input('shift_from')));

      $shift_to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Request::input('shift_to')));